# SSL Client Authentication using PHP

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I have a Java Servlet running on a Tomcat 7 server that uses Client Authentication.
I want to make a HTTP request from a PHP script to this server. I'm not that familiar with PHP but from what I found online it seems that the cURL library can be used for this task. I've read the cURL documentation but I didn't find any way of setting a certificate for client authentication. 
Am I missing something, is there any way to do this using cURL or is there any other PHP library that can be used for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) allows you to specify the path to your certificate.

Comment: Thanks, I've read the documentation but I've missed this option.